# Аномальные изменение размера папки postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, zabbix

На сервере имеется очень странное увеличение, а затем откат к начальному размеру папки postgres. Поднят zabbix server в связке с postgresql. С разной периодичностью папка postgres начинает увеличиваться на +-1GB (см. график). После чего уменьшается до начальных на момент роста значений. При этом размеры всех бд, которые находятся в postgres не имеют таких изменений. При этом такие скачки размера папки наблюдается с момента настройки zabbix server + postgres.[image: аномальное изменение размеров postgresql]

Comment: Сделайте в этот момент `du -sh *` в ней

Comment: Интенсивная вставка в БД и регулярный autovacuum, который чистит "мусор"? Каким именно способом проверяете "размеры всех бд"? Спрашиваю, чтоб понять видите ли в результате и мусор.

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, данные по размеру папки собираю так: 
sudo /usr/bin/du -bs /*путь до папки postgres*/ | awk '{print $1}'
А размеры отдельных бд, снимал с помощью шаблона "PostgreSQL by Zabbix agent"

Comment: ну а как rollback происходит о вашему, если внесённые изменения не нужны? сначала данные вводятся. а старые сохраняются. потом старые в вакуум или... остаются.

Comment: @nexoma меня смущает такой объем отката данных. И при этом занимаемое место до и после +- равное. Хотя я вручную запустил vacuum full, то после аналогичного скачка бд уменьшилась в размерах.

Comment: ну, тут надо изучать хранение структур в бд. в оракле данные в блоках, например, и делаются копии блоков. а не меняется отдельно какое-то поле в строке таблицы.

Comment: вот нашлось, страницы это. а не блоки https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/699812/